# Border style is applied as a background color in progress bar

Tags: html, css

I was testing a jsfiddle for an animated progress bar when I noticed something strange. I had one CSS rule on the `progress` tag:

```
progress {
    border:2px solid #ccc;
}
```

But the progress went from looking like this from before the CSS:

[image]

```html
<progress value="22" max="100">
</progress>
```

To this, after the CSS is applied:

[image]

```css
progress {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<progress value="22" max="100">
</progress>
```

Why is such a small change in the CSS making such a radical change in the look of the progress bar. For example, where is the green color coming from?

Comment: Can you provide more html and css?

Comment: It looks like adding *any* styling overrides the default user-agent styling...at least in Chrome. - See - http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/

Comment: @Soullighter Actually, the code provided is all that is necessary to reproduce the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `progress` elements are replaced elements, which don't behave like normal elements.

By default, browsers displays them in a "cool way". However, when you modify them, browsers switch to a "regular way" in order to be able to use your styles.

It happens the same with `button` elements.

```css
.border { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<progress value="70" max="100"></progress>
<button>Button</button>
<hr />
<progress value="70" max="100" class="border"></progress>
<button class="border">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The bar is being being reset to base styles when adding something. You can read more about the **[HTML 5 Progress Element](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/)**

Basically what's happening is the way you see it will render differently on browsers such as `-moz` and `-webkit-` based browsers.

To have it appear the same in all you will have to reset the styles of the `<progress>` element

```
progress{
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
-s-appearance:none;
-o-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
}
```

The same issue can be encountered when using the `<button>` element.

Here is a **[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2we5wor/)** to help explain. As you can see the top bar will be rendered based on your browser's rendering solution, the bottom escapes the renders and is styled through `CSS`.

Comment: @somethinghere Well Oriol beat me by a minute and his has the snippet, so I'm not going to bother to update, all of the information is in his.

Comment: Thats a quitters attitude! Its not because he beat you to the punch that your answer can't help other people understand it - sometimes different wording will help enlighten a topic! Ah well, its your choice.

Comment: @somethinghere added js fiddle.

Comment: I'll give that +1 , but SO has neat builtin snippets, which keeps you on the site. Next time, try that :)